# Show $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X^a}{Y^a}\right] \geq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^a]}{\mathbb{E}[Y^a]} $

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Given independent RVs $X$ and $Y$, with $Y>0$, $\mathbb{E}[Y^a]< \infty$ and  $\mathbb{E}[X^a]< \infty$ for some real $a\geq 0$.

I need to show that $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X^a}{Y^a}\right] \geq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^a]}{\mathbb{E}[Y^a]} $

My attempt is to assume that since $\mathbb{E}[Y^a]< \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^a]< \infty$ that they are $X,Y\in \mathcal{L}^a$

So for $\exists x,y:\mathbb{E}[X^a]\leq x,\mathbb{E}[Y^a]\leq y$. So Without loss of generality I can choose $\mathbb{E}[X^a]=\mathbb{E}[Y^a]=1$ and the linearity of expectation will allow me to extend it to all $X,Y\in\mathcal{L}^a$ by taking $\tilde{X}=\frac{X}{x}$ and  $\tilde{Y}=\frac{Y}{y}$.

All I must prove is $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X^a}{Y^a}\right] \geq 1$.

Is this a trivial consequence of $\mathbb{E}[X^a]=\mathbb{E}[Y^a]=1$ which I am missing? Or is there more work?

Comment: Why bother with $a$? If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X^a$ and $Y^a$ are independent. Don't you just have to prove it for $a=1$?

Comment: Try for example two uniform distributions between [0,1].  Their means are equal and 0.5.  However, the ratio distribution may not even have a finite mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathbb E(X^a/Y^a) = \mathbb E(X^a) \mathbb E(Y^{-a})$. The map $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is convex so the result follows by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: So $\displaystyle\mathbb{E}[X^a]\mathbb{E}[Y^a]^{-1} \leq \mathbb{E}[X^a]\mathbb{E}[Y^{-a}]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X^a}{Y^a}\right]$ is sufficient? (by Jensen's inequality first and independence second)

Comment: No first use the independence
$$ \mathbb E (X^a Y^{-a} ) = \mathbb E(X^a) \mathbb E(Y^{-a}).  $$
Then Jensen's inequality
$$ \mathbb E(Y^{-a}) \geq [\mathbb E(Y^a) ]^{-1}.   $$

Comment: That's what I did

Comment: yes ok you're right then, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $E[Y^{-a}]$ is finite, otherwise replace $Y$ by $\min\{Y,n\}$.

As $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E[X^aY^{-a}]=E[X^a]E[Y^{-a}|$, we only have to show that $E[Y^a]E[Y^{-a}]\geqslant 1$. It's a consequence of Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, with $Y^{a/2}$ and $Y^{-a/2}$.

Comment: So do you agree that showing that it is greater than 1 will prove the general case? What is meant by $\mathbb{E}[Y^a]\mathbb{E}[Y^{-a}]\geq 1$ where has $X$ gone?